# Why do I get an error about undefined reference to vtables in compilation of ANSI-C?

Tags: c, gcc, vtable

I am trying to compile C code with gcc and I get a compilation error that states

```
undefined reference to `vtable for __cxxabiv1::my_struct`
```

I am invoking gcc with the following options:

```
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -x c
```

The error message indicates to me that gcc views the code as C++ even though I clearly told it to treat it as plain C.

I tried to use -ansi instead of -std=c99, but that did not help.

I would expect a message about undefined symbols, but not about vtables, and I did not expect to see __cxxabiv1 in the error message.

Comment: Looks like a linker error, not a compile error. It's probably compiling your C module just fine. You're probably linking against some C++ modules but using gcc to do the linking . If any modules are C++, you need to use g++ to invoke the linker correctly. More detail required. Do you have a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: the error message mentions `::`, however, `::` is not found in C.